# Why only one of the qubits is rotated in the CHSH circuit?

Tags: qiskit, entanglement, non-locality, bell-experiment

When reading various [tutorials](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-demos/chsh.html) on how to calculate CHSH, there is only a single qubit which is rotated inside of the quantum circuit, it is also only ever rotated around a single axis.

I would like to understand why this is enough? As far as I understand, both Alice and Bob should be able to chose arbitrary measuring axis, but in the quantum tutorials we only ever allow Alice to rotate her qubit.

Comment: The actual experiment should try to rotate both detectors, but this is just a tutorial do not look too much into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an actual implementation of the CHSH game, **both Alice and Bob must conditionally rotate their qubit**. If one of them doesn't do any conditional operations to the qubit, then all the actions to the qubit could have been applied before the players were separated. Including measuring it. But that would mean the other qubit was no longer entangled, and could be described by a local hidden variable theory (the qubit's unentangled state vector), violating Bell's theorem.

That being said, something you can prove is that the state $|00\rangle + |11\rangle$ doesn't care which qubit is being rotated around the X axis. It is the case that

$$
\begin{aligned}
&R_{X1}(a+b) \cdot(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)
\\=&R_{X2}(a+b) \cdot (|00\rangle + |11\rangle)
\\=&R_{X1}(a)R_{X2}(b) \cdot (|00\rangle + |11\rangle)
\end{aligned}
$$

This is sort of core to why entangled states like this one can violate Bell's inequality. Even though you can't communicate, you can do a thing that results in rotation angles being added together, and then measure something with correlations that depend on the amount of rotation.

It's possible that an explanation might start by explaining what happens when rotating just one qubit, before moving on to explaining that this actually explains what happens when rotating both qubits. But it's very important to include the latter part.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that allowing only one of the two experimenters to choose their observable is insufficient for a realization of the CHSH experiment.

However, this is not what the linked qiskit tutorial describes. If you have another look at *all* the circuits in the tutorial, you will notice that both Alice and Bob get to make a choice. Specifically, Bob chooses between $X$ and $Z$ measurement basis while Alice makes a choice between two bases dependent on the angle $\theta$. The choices materialize in the circuit in the presence or absence of an additional Hadamard gate immediately before measurement. Thus, there are two options for Alice and two options for Bob and hence four different circuits overall.

In fact, this is explicitly stated in the tutorial

> While Bob ($q_1$) always measures either in the computational basis or the $X$ basis, Alice's measurement basis rotates by the angle θ with respect to Bob's.

Note also that the angle $\theta$ does not encode any of the choices. Rather, it encodes the relationship between the two measurement bases available to Bob and the measurement bases available to Alice. This is why the $Y$ rotation is present in all four circuits. That said, one is of course free to consider multiple realizations of the CHSH experiment for varying $\theta$, which is also something the tutorial does.

Comment: I'm pretty sure both parties have to conditionally apply rotations to their qubit. Otherwise, by the deferred measurement principle, one party could measure their qubit before being separated and the resulting expectations would be identical. But that would trace their qubit out of the system, allowing a local description of the qubits belong to the other party, giving a local hidden variable strategy, violating Bell's theorem.

Comment: @CraigGidney Yes, as I wrote above, both parties decide what observable to measure via the conditional Hadamard on their respective qubits. If you use deferred measurement principle to remove entanglement then the conditional Hadamard from one qubit effectively moves to the other qubit, so the hidden variables for Bob's qubit would have to somehow incorporate Alice's choice! This is in perfect agreement with Bell's theorem: the hidden variable strategy you propose fails to be local.